# update image from a custom adapter listview android

Tags: android, listview

I need to update my listview that contain a image and a button, the problem than i have is with the index, the app always update the second index of the listview, if i have 2 rows (imagen+ button each),always the second imagen is updated using both buttons, the 2 buttons update only the second image and the first not.

this is my code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewclientes, null);
            holder = new CustomAdapterPublicidad.ViewHolder();

            holder.publicidadboton = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.publicidadboton);
            holder.publicidadimagen = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.publicidadimagen);


            final RowItemPublicidad row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

            holder.publicidadimagen.setImageResource(row_pos.getFotoPublicidad());
            holder.publicidadboton.setText(row_pos.getBoton());

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (CustomAdapterPublicidad.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.publicidadboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(position==0){
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from(user.getUid() + "tienda1").withHint(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 0).bitmap();
                    holder.publicidadimagen.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else if(position==1) {
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from(user.getUid() + "tienda2").withHint(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 0).bitmap();
                    holder.publicidadimagen.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using RecyclerView or ListView?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the `if position(int)` inside `onClick()` is run once the button is clicked, and by that time position is always 1. Instead, change what `onClick ()` does before the button is clicked. (while the position is the value you are trying get)

change your code to this:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewclientes, null);
            holder = new CustomAdapterPublicidad.ViewHolder();    
            holder.publicidadboton = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.publicidadboton);             
            holder.publicidadimagen = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.publicidadimagen);



            final RowItemPublicidad row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

            holder.publicidadimagen.setImageResource(row_pos.getFotoPublicidad());
            holder.publicidadboton.setText(row_pos.getBoton());

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (CustomAdapterPublicidad.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (position==0) {
            holder.publicidadboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from(user.getUid() + "tienda1").withHint(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 0).bitmap();
                    holder.publicidadimagen.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();    
                }
            }
        }) else if (position==1) {
            holder.publicidadboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from(user.getUid() + "tienda2").withHint(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 0).bitmap();
                    holder.publicidadimagen.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();  
                }
            }
        };

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: im still got the same issue, only updates de second picture, both buttons update the second index

Comment: maybe the error is: first i need the image position and after that, update the image, i dont know what to do at this time

Answer (score 0):

Write the `position` check inside `onBindViewHolder` or inside the `viewHolder` class.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
  holder.publicidadboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(position==0){
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from(user.getUid() + "tienda1").withHint(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 0).bitmap();
                    holder.publicidadimagen.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else if(position==1) {
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from(user.getUid() + "tienda2").withHint(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 0).bitmap();
                    holder.publicidadimagen.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
}
```